# How to show custom application metrics in Prometheus captured using the golang client library from all pods running in Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-go-client, prometheus-operator

I am trying to get some custom application metrics captured in golang using the prometheus client library to show up in Prometheus.

I have the following working:

- I have a go application which is exposing metrics on localhost:8080/metrics as described in this article:

  https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus
- I have a kubernates minikube running which has Prometheus, Grafana and AlertManager running using the operator from this article:

  https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/contrib/kube-prometheus
- I created a docker image for my go app, when I run it and go to localhost:8080/metrics I can see the prometheus metrics showing up in a browser.
- I use the following pod.yaml to deploy my docker image to a pod in k8s

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: my-app-pod
>   labels:
>     zone: prod
>     version: v1
>   annotations:
>    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
>    prometheus.io/port: '8080'
>
> spec:
>    containers:
>     - name: my-container
>       image: name/my-app:latest
>       imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
>       ports:
>       - containerPort: 8080
> ```

- If I connect to my pod using:

> kubectl exec -it my-app-pod -- /bin/bash

then do wget on "localhost:8080/metrics", I can see my metrics

So far so good, here is where I am hitting a wall. I could have multiple pods running this same image. I want to expose all the images to prometheus as targets. How do I configure my pods so that they show up in prometheus so I can report on my custom metrics?

Thanks for any help offered!

Comment: Not sure about the operator, never used this one but I manually deployed Prometheus on Kube [like so](https://github.com/openshift-demos/resorcerer#launch-prometheus) (and in case you wonder, you can ignore the OpenShift specific things, that's just convenience). The biggest help and my permanent reference was indeed the official [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#<kubernetes_sd_config>) on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 things:

- a ServiceMonitor for the Prometheus Operator, which specifies which services will be scraped for metrics
- a Service which matches the ServiceMonitor and points to your pods

There is an example in the docs over here: https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/user-guides/running-exporters.html

Answer (score 2):

The kubernetes_sd_config directive can be used to discover all pods with a given tag. Your Prometheus.yml config file should have something like so:

`- job_name: 'some-app'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
      regex: python-app
      action: keep`

The source label [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app] is basically using the Kubernetes api to look at pods that have a label of 'app' and whose value is captured by the regex expression, given on the line below (in this case, matching 'python-app').

Once you've done this Prometheus will automatically discover the pods you want and start scraping the metrics from your app.

Hope that helps. You can follow blog post [here](http://burhan.io/flask-application-monitoring-with-prometheus/) for more detail.

**Note:** it is worth mentioning that at the time of writing, kubernetes_sd_config is still in beta. Thus breaking changes to configuration may occur in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the prometheus config that you are using to scrape the metrics. The config will control what all sources to scrape the metrics from. Here are a few links that you can refer to : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/prometheus-users/Application$20metrics$20monitoring$20of$20Kubernetes$20Pods%7Csort:relevance/prometheus-users/uNPl4nJX9yk/cSKEBqJlBwAJ